# Books for understanding math logic and proofs related to physics

Tags: calculus

I'm an undergrad for physics right now, but I'm really interested in the logical thinking on how some of the maths used in physics came to be, and I guess some of the proofs on why it works/is used. I'd like book recommendations for beginning to understand the "meat and potatoes" behind functions, calculus, operators etc.

Like the inception of calculus and the logical reasoning of integrals and infinitesimals and why we can apply a Riemann integral to a velocity vs time graph to find the distance.

I feel like I have a more or less intuitive grasp on trigonometry and "why it makes sense to me" that we use trig functions cos(),sin() or what have you here or there. But I find calculus to be a bit more of a jump in intuition that I do not have right now.

TL;DR I want to know/be able to explain why this math is used, not the "because it gives us what we want" why, but the "undeniable proof/reasoning" why.

Comment: I think V. Arnol'd's book about classical mechanics might help you here.

Comment: Integration is the inverse of taking derivative; this is a purely mathematical fact (fundamental theorem of calculus; of course arguably it comes from physics intuition). In physics we believe that the derivative of distance is velocity, so we must also believe the integral of velocity is distance (more precisely position). Do you know the $\epsilon-\delta$ language in calculus? It's the way math people talk about "infinitesimals". It should be covered in most decent calculus books.

Comment: Also for some reason you added the logic tag, which doesn't seem too relevant to your question, but my suggestion is always *How to Prove It* by Velleman.

Comment: @1830rbc03 I was thinking it would relate to understanding of math, but seeing as there is a whole field dedicated to mathematical logic, I can see how it is a little misleading